# Prevent flooding of Logic App http endpoint

Tags: azure, rest, api, vue.js, azure-logic-apps

So the problem i am having is that i'm scared someone will flood my mailchimp account with trash email addresses. I'm currently working on a website where we will do a sign-up for emails. The website is build in Vue.js and uses Axios to call a Azure Logic App. The post towards the logic app contains a json with an email address inside.

What's particularly scaring me is that someone would be able to paste the javascript code from the button onto the console and just flood the logic app.
Logic App actions costs money and flooding it would cost me money and a datalist full of trash email accounts.

Would someone know if you're able to restrict Logic apps and check if there has been a request made already from that specific user agent? Creating a database just to save this data seems unnecessary and would also cost you like 23euro a month on azure.

I'm constantly trying to think about solutions but vue.js handles everything client sided. I Expect to create a email form that submits to an Logic App endpoint but that can't be flooded by a single user or bad actor.

Any help is welcome. And as always thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you have some kind of backend?

Comment: For now no, as this is the only call that has to be made. Everything else is staticly hosted.

Comment: Instead of a database, you could use Table Storage but that won't solve your restrict problem.  You could use a Function that will check Table Storage.  Functions are cheaper but I guess that you wanted to use the Mailchimp connector.  From your Function and after your check Table Storage, you could send a message to a Queue Storage and have the Logic App be triggered by  new messages.  Or create a simple backend API ;-)

Comment: It seems like a bit of an overkill in your case, but another way to restrict access to your logic app by putting an API Gateway in front of it (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies) + restrict access to the logic app only to the IP addresses of the API management so it is no longer accessible from any IP.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid logic app have no proper way to handle scenario.But I think it will be a workaround for you :

On your JS static front-end, you can implement a timer to make sure your logic app endpoint can be called i,e one time per 60s from your front-end. What's more you should obfuscate your JS code to make sure your code logic can't be modified easily.

However, this way not works if attacker runs numerous of your front-end instance to call logic app endpoint. So for this scenario , the best way is implement a backend to block malicious calls .